# How do I add CloudWatch logging for an EC2 Instance (and Spot Fleets) Using Python Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I am using python with boto3 to create AWS EC2 instances (as well as making spot fleet requests) but I cannot figure out how to add CloudWatch logging to the ec2 instances or spot fleets.

I know how to add logging via the AWS Console but I need to know how programmatically via boto3.

I have been looking through the documentation via the following link but I cannot find an answer:
https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html

I have noticed the ConnectionLogOptions but it does not appear to be available for the request_spot_fleet or create_instances.

Can anyone provide an example of how to configure CloudWatch logging when using boto3 to create ec2 instances or make spot fleet requests?

Here is an example of my create_instance configuration:

```
    instances = ec2.create_instances(
    ImageId='ami-00000000000000000',
    InstanceInitiatedShutdownBehavior='terminate',
    InstanceType='t2.medium',
    MaxCount=1,
    UserData=userData,
    MinCount=1,
    TagSpecifications=[{
        'ResourceType': 'instance',
        'Tags': [
            {'Key': tag,
             'Value':  tag_value}]}],
    NetworkInterfaces=[{
        'SubnetId': "subnet-00000000",
        'DeviceIndex': 0,
        "DeleteOnTermination": True,
        'AssociatePublicIpAddress': True,
        'Groups': ["sg-ef000000"]
    }],
    KeyName=keyname)
```

Here is an example of the spot fleet request:

```
    request=client.request_spot_fleet(
    SpotFleetRequestConfig= {
        "IamFleetRole": "arn:aws:iam::000000000:role/my-role",
        "AllocationStrategy": "lowestPrice",
        "TargetCapacity": int(target_capacity),
        "SpotPrice": "0.052",
        "ValidFrom": date_from.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'),
        "ValidUntil": date_to.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'),
        "TerminateInstancesWithExpiration": True,
        "LaunchSpecifications": [
            {
            "ImageId": ami_id,
            "InstanceType": "t3.small",
            "KeyName": pemkey,
            "SpotPrice": "0.0236",
            "BlockDeviceMappings": [
                {
                "DeviceName": "/dev/sda1",
                "Ebs": {
                    "DeleteOnTermination": True,
                    "VolumeType": "gp2",
                    "VolumeSize": 8,
                    "SnapshotId": ami_snapshot_id
                }
                }
            ],
            "UserData": userdata,
            "NetworkInterfaces": [
                {
                "DeviceIndex": 0,
                "SubnetId": "subnet-0000000",
                "DeleteOnTermination": True,
                "Groups": [
                    "sg-0000000"
                ],
                "AssociatePublicIpAddress": True
                }
            ],
            "TagSpecifications": [
                {
                "ResourceType": "instance",
                "Tags": [
                    {
                    "Key": tag,
                    "Value": tag_value
                    }
                ]
                }
            ]
            }
        ],
        "Type": "request"
    }
)
```

Comment: What do you mean by "add CloudWatch logging to the ec2 instances or spot fleets"? What logging do you want?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, I want to be able to push logs (print statements, python logging, etc) to cloudwatch from scripts/apps running within the EC2 instances.  I know how to configure the cloudwatch awslogs-group and awslogs-region within an ECS, but I don't see how this is done via the boto3 client.

Comment: You would need to [Collect Metrics and Logs from Amazon EC2 Instances and On-Premises Servers with the CloudWatch Agent](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/Install-CloudWatch-Agent.html).